# Set value of controlgroup radiobutton

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I need to be able to dynamically set the value of items in a JQM control group, but I've been unable to do so. Here is the html markup:

```
<div>
  <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" id="searchType" class="center">
    <legend></legend>
    <input name="radio-choice-h-4" id="radio-choice-h-4a" value="1" type="radio"/>
    <label for="radio-choice-h-4a">First</label>
    <input name="radio-choice-h-4" id="radio-choice-h-4b" type="radio"/>
    <label for="radio-choice-h-4b">Previous</label>
    <input name="radio-choice-h-4" id="radio-choice-h-4c" type="radio"/>
    <label for="radio-choice-h-4c">Next</label>
    <input name="radio-choice-h-4" id="radio-choice-h-4d" type="radio"/>
    <label for="radio-choice-h-4d">Last</label>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

And my [simplified] JS / JQ which I'm calling from FireBug console for testing:

```
$('input[name=radio-choice-h-4d]').val(6).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

I also have some JS to create a pop-up when one of the button is clicked. This shows the value of the button to be 'on'.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong &/or how to get it to work?

Comment: The Name attribute is for the group of checkboxes. IF you are trying to set the value of a particular checkbox, you can use its ID: $('#radio-choice-h-4a').val(6);. If you are only setting the value and not the checked state, you do not need the checkboxradio("refresh");

Comment: You don't need to refresh, you aren't changing the state of checkbox.

Comment: @ezanker Doh! It doesn't help that I was trying to call it by name rather than id, either. Thanks. Ill accept this as an answer if you want to post it..

Comment: @Omar, that was out of desperation just to check. Thanks.